# iOS Swift Handle notification click when app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to handle notification click action when app is terminated
when i click the notification my app just lunch first screen as normal lunch
not the expected screen
i don't now or how can i debug this problem to find out what happening exactly

when app is running or in background mode, i handle my notification click actions through this method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                       didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                       withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID) tap")
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .remoteNotificationActionName, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        print("willPresent userInfo", userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
```

this notification will send to scene delegate class and from my scene delegate i will open the appropriate screen:

```
@objc
private func remoteNotificationClickAction(notification: Notification){
    performRemoteNotificationClickAction(notification: notification)
}

private func performRemoteNotificationClickAction(notification: Notification){
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
    guard let clickAction = NotificationsActions(rawValue: userInfo["click_action"] as? String ?? "") else { return }
    switch clickAction {
    case .dashboardAds:
        routeToNotifications()
    case .dashboardAdsContent:
        routeToNotifications()
    case .providerAcceptOrder, .providerOnWay, .providerArrive, .tripStarted, .addReceiverToChat:
        guard let orderString = userInfo["order"] as? String else { return }
        routeToActiveOrder(orderString: orderString)
    case .orderComplete:
        guard let orderString = userInfo["order"] as? String else { return }
        routeToServiceReport(orderString: orderString)
    case .orderCanceled, .receiverTracking, .receiverCancelOrder, .transportationDocumentIssued, .adminCancelOrder, .userCancelOrder:
        guard let orderString = userInfo["order"] as? String else { return }
        self.routeToOrderDetails(orderString: orderString)
    case .providerCancelOrderAccepted, .offerAdded, .receiverTrackingAccept, .orderExpired, .receiverTrackingReject, .offerWithdrawn:
        guard let orderString = userInfo["order"] as? String else { return }
        routeToSearchForServiceProvider(orderString: orderString)
    case .messageReceive:
        guard let orderString = userInfo["order"] as? String else { return }
        routeToChat(orderString: orderString)
    case .amountSent, .amountReceive, .amountAdded, .amountSubtracted, .withdrawAccepted, .withdrawRejected, .bankTransferAccepted, .bankTransferRejected:
        routeToWallet()
    case .pointsAdded:
        routeToTopUpPoints()
    case .reportClosed:
        routeToComplaints()
    default:  break
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you find the answer??

Comment: yes I post the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    whereToGo(window!)
    if let notificationResponse = connectionOptions.notificationResponse{
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .remoteNotificationActionName, object: nil, userInfo: notificationResponse.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    }
}
```

as shown in above code my notification received in **connectionOptions.notificationResponse**

Answer (score 1):

When app is in killed/terminated state, didReceiveRemoteNotification method will not be called. Then on the tap of notification application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) method will be called. launchOption contains the payload if app is launched by tap on notification. For that write the given code in this method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       if launchOptions != nil{
         let userInfo = launchOptions? 
         [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]
          if userInfo != nil {
        // Perform action here
         }
    }
```

All your payload data will be available in launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] & perform your app logic(navigation..) from there.

Comment: launchOptions? 
         [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] is always nil